# hg convert, Subversion python bindings error

Tags: python, svn, mercurial, mercurial-convert

I'm trying to convert a subversion repository to mercurial a one and at this point I'm just banging my head against the wall.

On the current windows server the following programs are installed:

- Visual SVN Server,
- TortoiseHg,
- Python2.7

In my console I run the command

```
 hg convert [dest] [source]
```

Which gives a lot of errors about the repository being of different types and also this

```
 could not load Subversion python bindings
```

After some googling I found that those bindings are supposed to be included with TortoiseHg, but as I already mentioned I have TortoiseHg installed and it's still not working. I then tried to download the svn python bindings and read somewhere that I should add them in the Python27/Lib/site-packages directory but it's still not working. I think that I maybe have to recompile those bindings with python or something, but I've never used python so I'm pretty lost

Comment: Did you try to re-install tortoiseHG so that it can fix any borkeness? If that doesn't help, did you try to install it manually? Which versions do you use? Which OS environment? Also urgently read https://secure.phabricator.com/book/phabflavor/article/please_please_please/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. You used parameters in incorrect order

   hg convert [OPTION]... SOURCE [DEST [REVMAP]]
2. For TortoiseHG 3.4 and later you must to download and enable [Subversion bindings](https://bitbucket.org/tortoisehg/thg/wiki/libsvn) as separate extension

> ```
> [extensions]
> ...
> svnbindings = c:\insertpath.py
> ```

3. Even if you have Subversion-binding in Mercurial (try and show **here** output of`hg version --svn`), you can't convert 1.8 repositories with `file:///` access-protocol, only with *any* networking

> ```
> >hg version --svn
> ...
> hgsubversion: 538bbb927609
> Subversion: 1.7.5
> bindings: SWIG
> ```

```
>hg convert file:///Z:/SVN
assuming destination SVN-hg
initializing destination SVN-hg repository
abort: repository 'file:///Z:/SVN' is not local
```

Z:\SVN repo was created with plain `svnadmin create`

```
>hg convert file:///Z:/SVN17
assuming destination SVN17-hg
initializing destination SVN17-hg repository
scanning source...
sorting...
converting...
0 Initial data
```

Z:\SVN17 was created with `--compatible-version 1.7` option